# Problem with Angular JSON GET request from ASP.NET Core api

Tags: json, .net, angular, api, asp.net-core

**I am trying to make Angular Front-End + Asp.Net Core api Back-end project. I had get method in my api controller which returns JSON array of "ActorDTO". I have succesfully tested my  GET method in Postman app, but when I started to develop my angular part of project, request works(no console error like BadRequest etc.) but my local array of object "Actor" is undefined. I can`t find my error please help me.**

My Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ActorDTO>> getActors()
    {
        var entities = await _context.actors.ToListAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<List<Actor>, List<ActorDTO>>(entities);
    }
```

Actor entity:

```
 public class Actor
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Fathername { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CountFilms { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

My ActorDTO model:

```
public class ActorDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Fathername { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CountFilms { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Typescript Actor Model:

```
export class ActorModel{
public Id: number;
public Name: string;
public Surname: string;
public Fathername: string;
public Country: string;
public CountFilms: number;
public Description: string;
public BirthYear: number;
public Age: number;
public PictureUrl: string;

construstor(){
    this.Id = null;
    this.Name = null;
    this.Surname = null;
    this.Fathername = null;
    this.Country = null;
    this.CountFilms = null;
    this.Description = null;
    this.BirthYear = null;
    this.Age = null;
    this.PictureUrl = null;
}
```

}

Angular Actor Service:

```
import { ActorModel } from './../../Models/actor.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiResult } from 'src/app/Models/result.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ActorService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  baseUrl = 'api/actor/';

  getAllActor(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
  }

  getActor(id: number){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/get/' + id);
  }

  addActor(model : ActorModel){
    return this.http.post<ApiResult>(this.baseUrl + '/addactor/' , model);
  }
```

}

actor.component.ts where I am subscribing to GET request

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActorModel } from './../Models/actor.model';
import { ActorService } from './../services/actor-service/actor.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actors',
  templateUrl: './actors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./actors.component.css']
})
export class ActorsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private actorService: ActorService, private router: Router) { }

  thisUrl: string;
  actors: ActorModel[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.thisUrl = this.router.url;
    this.actorService.getAllActor().subscribe(
      (list: ActorModel[]) => {
        this.actors = list;
        console.log(this.actors[0].Name);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

console.log(this.actors[0].Name) - here when I check console I see "undefined". What's wrong? I really cant understand.

Comment: baseUrl seems suspicious with a trailing '/'. `this.baseUrl + '/get/'` will give `api/actor//get/'`

Comment: @RoarS. fixed this but still not working, just the same undefined

Comment: Please compare the URLs you are using in Postman with the URLs you are using in your js. I suspect you're having routing issues.

Comment: @RoarS. thanks. Yes, this.http was undefined so the str befor 'api/get ' was empty without ""localhost:xxxx". Thanks one more time